# PHP rotate imported and processed PDF file in MPDF library

Tags: php, mpdf

Would anyone know how to rotate an imported PDF document in MPDF library ? I have been looking for the solution for a long time.

here is my code :

```
//Whith curl I import external PDF file $onlineimportedPDFfile

$mpdf->AddPage('P');
                
$mpdf->SetImportUse();
$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile($onlineimportedPDFfile);
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount,0,0,297,210);
$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
```

The page is in portrait format, but the imported file is in landscape format...

Thank you for your answers